# How do I create an input stream that reads from a string instead of a file or url

Tags: clojure, inputstream

I want to bind `*in*` to stream that's reading from a string instead of the "real" input stream.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out `with-in-str`:

http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/with-in-str

ClojureDocs has an example of its use:

```
;; Given you have a function that will read from *in*
(defn prompt [question]
  (println question)
  (read-line))

user=> (prompt "How old are you?")
How old are you?
34                   ; <== This is what you enter
"34"                 ; <== This is returned by the function

;; You can now simulate entering your age at the prompt by using with-in-str

user=> (with-in-str "34" (prompt "How old are you?"))
How old are you?
"34"                 ; <== The function now returns immediately
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's the correct answer to the question, but what I actually ended up really needing was a little different.  See the answer below.

Comment: Could you please add an example too, as the link you provided does not have one either.

Comment: Clojuredocs has an example: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/with-in-str

Answer (score 5):

Here's sample code for what I ended up doing.  The idea is a simple server read/print loop function which takes an in and out stream.  My issue was how to generate testing streams for such a function, and I thought a string function would do.  Instead this is what I needed:

```
(ns test
    (:use [clojure.java.io :only [reader writer]]))
(def prompt ">")
(defn test-client [in out]
  (binding [*in* (reader in)
            *out* (writer out)]
           (print prompt) (flush)

(loop [input (read-line)]
             (when input
               (println (str "OUT:" input))
               (print prompt) (flush)
               (if (not= input "exit\n") (recur (read-line)) )
               ))))
(def client-stream (java.io.PipedWriter.))
(def r (java.io.BufferedReader. (java.io.PipedReader. client-stream)))
(doto (Thread. #(do (test-client r *out*))) .start)

(.write client-stream "test\n")
```